# Ambiguous angle for projectile

Tags: classical-mechanics, projectile

A projectile is launched with at an angle $\theta$ to the horizontal with speed $v_o$ along an incline of $\alpha$ to the horizontal. Find the angle of projection that maximizes the distance traveled along the incline.

Assume that $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}\le\alpha\le\frac{\pi}{2}$, and $\theta\gt\alpha$

I managed to prove that the distance the projectile lands along the incline is

$$D=\frac{2{v_o}^2\sin(\theta-\alpha)\cos(\theta)}{g\cos^2(\alpha)}$$

So maximizing $\theta$ means maximizing

$$f(\theta)=\sin(\theta-\alpha)\cos(\theta)$$
So
$$f(\theta)=(\sin(\theta)\cos(\alpha)-\cos(\theta)\sin(\alpha))\cos(\theta)\\=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)\cos(\alpha)-\cos^2(\theta)\sin(\alpha)$$

Differentiating and solving gives

$$f'(\theta)=\cos(2\theta)\cos(\alpha)+\sin(2\theta)\sin(\alpha)\\\cos(2\theta)\cos(\alpha)+\sin(2\theta)\sin(\alpha)=0\\\cos(2\theta-\alpha)=0\\2\theta-\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}\\\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\alpha}{2}$$

This is the correct answer, but since $\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$, I could have used $\cos(\alpha-2\theta)$, which would have given me $\theta=\frac{\alpha}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}$

I'm unsure how to know that the former is correct.

Comment: Hint: Draw a diagram. What does it mean physically if $\theta<\alpha$?

Comment: What's the difference between an angle theta with the horizontal and an incline of alpha to the horizontal?

Comment: $\theta$ is the launch angle of the projectile with respect to the horizontal, and $\alpha$ is the angle of the inclined plane with respect to the horizontal in which the projectile is fired upon

Comment: Just in terms of the Mathematics you need to check the value of $f''(\theta) = 2\sin(\alpha-2\theta)$ to see if you are dealing with a maximum or a minimum.